# Globally mark (tag) an object passed as function argument (e. g. via an attribute)

Tags: r

I am trying to mark an object as "already processed" in my function and played around with attributes. This does not work because R makes a local copy when I set an attribute so I am changing a copy but not the original object:

```
x <- "object 1"
attr(x, "attr1") <- TRUE

setAttr2 <- function(o) {
  attr(o, "attr2") <- TRUE
  invisible(NULL)  # no return value possible
}

x
# [1] "object 1"
# attr(,"attr1")
# [1] TRUE

setAttr2(x)
x               # the attribute has not been set
# [1] "object 1"
# attr(,"attr1")
# [1] TRUE
```

How could I change the original object (variable `x`) from within the function?

**PS: I cannot use the return value of my function since the caller will ignore this** (more exactly: I am within the error handler function of `tryCatch` and want to "tag" the error condition object passed as first argument to the error handler function by R):

```
tryCatch(stop("damn"),
         error = function(e) {
           attr(e, "my.tag") <- TRUE;
           # ...
         })
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you...

```
setAttr2 <- function(o) {
  var <- deparse(substitute(o))
  var_2 <- get(var)
  attr(var_2, "attr2") <- TRUE
  var_2
}

setAttr2(x)

> setAttr2(x)
[1] "object 1"
attr(,"attr2")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: THX, good idea to use `get`! I have tried it but I think it does not work (e. g. `setAttr2(x); x` shows that just the return value of your functions has `attr2` but not `x` after the function call. Strange thing...

Comment: Is there a reason that `x <- setAttr2(x)` won't work for you?

Comment: The reason for not being able to use the return value is that I am within an error condition handler function of R where I want to add an attribute to the condition object (argument `e` below) and I cannot change R to consider my return value: `tryCatch(stop("damn"), error = function(e) { attr(e, "my.tag") <- TRUE; # ... })`

Comment: I see. Sorry. I'll think on this some more.